# Question about sample space

Tags: probability

Here, the author says we no longer need to describe $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}$). But I wonder what the sample space is.
[image: Sample space]
Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of the sample space fully describe what happened in the experiment. Often, there are a few different choices you could make. Here, I might describe the sample space as follows: Label all the balls: $W^1_1, W^1_2$ are the two white balls initially in urn one, $W^2_1,W^2_2, W^2_3$ are the three white balls initially in urn two. Similarly for blue. Then your sample space consists of pairs $(B_1,B_2),$ where $B_1$ is the ball you transferred from urn one to urn two and $B_2$ is the ball you drew from urn two at the end. Each element in $\Omega$ has the same probability provided it's 'legal' (i.e. $B_1$ is one of the balls in urn one and $B_2$ is either a ball from urn two or it is $B_1$), otherwise has probability zero.

Comment: Thanks! As you've mentioned, there're different choices. So, could you please give some other choices? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Thomasshinwee Different encodings of the same information are possible, like you can imagine the balls are in different buckets (say labeled $1-5$ and $1-8$ in the first and second urn and then you place the transferred ball into bucket number $8$ in the second urn) then your sample space is a bucket from the first urn followed by a bucket from the second. Also you can arguably do reductions that don't have all of the information but retain the info you care about. Like your sample space can be a pair of colors (first draw and second draw) or just the color of the last one.

Comment: @Thomasshinwee But the ones that lose information will require more calculation to figure out the probabilities and there's the issue of what if you decide you want to include events that rely on the missing information.